# Cannot see data from newly created file using 'fs.createWriteStream'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm having issues with reading the data from a file created with fs.createWriteStream.

It looks like the stream.write get executed at the end of the program after the file is read as opposed to when they are called (which would explain why there is nothing in variable_3 at the time of outputting it).

The function used is as follow (simplified):

```
module.exports = async data1 => {
    console.log('start');
    try {
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename_1, { flags: "a" });
        console.log('stream created');
        stream.write("some data", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log("data written");
            }
        });

        for (const variable_1 of object_1) {
            const variable_2 = await function2({
                // generates a buffer
            });
            stream.write(variable_2, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("data written");
                }
            });
        }

        stream.end();
        console.log('stream ended');

        console.log('opening file');
        const variable_3 = fs.readFileSync(filename_1);
        console.log('file opened and read with data: ' + variable_3);
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

```
Output:
> start
> stream created
> stream ended
> opening file
> file opened and read with data: 
> data written
> data written
```

Once the code has run however, when I open filename_1 (via the explorer), the whole data is present?!

Comment: `await stream.end();` makes little sense. `end` function does not return a Promise. It takes a callback instead. Same thing for `await stream.write(variable_2)`. `write` returns a flag if you should wait for drain event or continue writing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have edited the OP. Would you have any suggestions regarding the data not being available when queried in `console.log(variable_3)`?

Comment: After more investigations, I have found that the data seems to be written at the end of the program instead of when called. I have updated the post to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Got it sorted in the end.

Didn't realise the stream functions don't return a promise so I had to manually return a promise.

Here is the code changed:

```
module.exports = async data1 => {
    console.log('start');
    try {
        const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename_1, { flags: "a" });
        console.log('stream created');
        stream.write("some data", (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            } else {
                console.log("data written");
            }
        });

        for (const variable_1 of object_1) {
            const variable_2 = await function2({
                // generates a buffer
            });
            stream.write(variable_2, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("data written");
                }
            });
        }

        stream.end();
        console.log('stream ended');

        console.log('opening file');
        const variable_3 = fs.readFileSync(filename_1);
        console.log('file opened and read with data: ' + variable_3);

        return new Promise(resolve => {
          stream.on('finish', () => {
              resolve('done');
              console.log("createNRRD is done");
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```